# Writing a WCF service to receive data from PUSH service

Tags: wcf, push

I have to write WCF service which receive data from remote PUSHED service which is non WCF Service, I am bit struggling to get the idea. can some one shred the light on this (some sample code highly appreciated).


Thank you

Comment: Did you try googling for Duplex Message exchange patterns in WCF.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff395349.aspx

Comment: Also try reading this link:http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=721

Comment: saravanan, Thank you for your quick replies, i was looking in to the same link which you added here. just to clarify, after I hosted a wcf service on IIS on my end, when ever client/server other end pushes the data, how do i know, that i got a data and do the process? do i need to integrate with MSMQ here?